# How to make camera zoom with scroll wheel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a camera that zooms in when you scroll up and zoom out when you scroll down. This is for a 2D camera but when I scroll the orthographic size flickers and goes back to the original orthographic size. This is the code and the two if statements are there to make sure you can't zoom out infinitely. Someone please help me fix this.

```cs
Camera.main.orthographicSize = (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y + 11) * -1;
if (Camera.main.orthographicSize < -50)
{
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = -50;
}
if (Camera.main.orthographicSize > -1)
{
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = -1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe tag this a little better for it to reach your target audience

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the `Input.mouseScrollDelta.y` doesn't hold value about how much you have scrolled already, but the amount you have scrolled since the last frame. As so, every frame you go back to the original camera size, modified only by how much you have scrolled since the last frame.

If you try logging `Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta.y);` your mouse delta, you will see, that if you don't scroll at all, it will stay on 0, hence the `(Input.mouseScrollDelta.y + 11) * -1` expression will always evaluate to -11, and it won't stay at the scroll value you wish it would.

You need to save a value you have scrolled so far yourself, for eg. like this:

```
class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentScrollDelta = 11f;

    private void Update()
    {
        currentScrollDelta += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = currentScrollDelta * -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other mouse scroll wheel input that I can use that records itself and if not how do I put the first part in a different class because I am completely lost on that.

Comment: @ThatGuyMatt I'm not aware of such. Btw, you don't need to put it in another class. What I said, is to put it in class body, not update method body, so it won't be overwritten every frame.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. What is class body? And how do I get the variable to work in the other body because with my understanding the variable has to be in that body for it to work? I'm sorry, I'm really new at programming.

Comment: In the class body, meaning: class Example { float variable = 11; //here void update() { // update code } } So just between curly braces of the class. Method body will be between curly braces of the method for example. If you want it to declare in the other class, you can, but then you need to reference object of that class in your script.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe it will be clearer @ThatGuyMatt

Comment: Putting the variable above the void update() causes the program to come back with the error: Use of unassigned local variable. The program is not using the code that is above the void update. 
`public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{float scrollDelta = 10;
    void Update() ` 
This is the scrolling code:
`float scrollDelta = scrollDelta + Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = scrollDelta * -1f;`